# How to sync a variable through Photon PUN

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, photon

I need to sync a variable so all the players have the same value.
I have tried with something like this

```
[PunRPC]
void Setting ()
{
I = somevalue;
//I Is my int
}
```

And I call it the following way:

```
PhotonView PV = GetComponent<PhotonView>();
PV.RPC("Setting", RPCTargets.All);
```

But the int value is null.
What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Did you try to pass it on as parameter instead?

Comment: @derHugo Do you mean putting an int parameter in Setting and writing I as the parameter to use?

Comment: Sorry I don't know how Photon works at all but in UNet you would have done something like `[ClientRpc] public void RpcSetting(int value){ myInt = value}` (and calling `RpcSetting(myInt);` on the **Server**) where `myInt` is the variable you want to set on all clients. I guess it is somehow similar in photon.

Answer (score 2):

You must pass parameter on function to all client can get this parameter. Just change your code to:

```
[PunRPC]
void Setting (int someValue)
{
I = somevalue;
}

void CallSetting()
{
PhotonView PV = GetComponent<PhotonView>();
PV.RPC("Setting", RPCTargets.All, someValue);
}
```

You can pass **PhotonMessageInfo**  additional on Setting fucntion to know more information of this client take setting call.

```
[PunRPC]
void Setting (int someValue,  PhotonMessageInfo info)
{
}
```