# Access to a PhotonView component

Tags: unity-game-engine, photon

I need to access the *INT* of this component.

I am using a **Photon View**, and I want to set a conditional if a GameObject has that "*INT*" value.[This is the Component](https://i.stack.imgur.com/C3a8d.png)

Comment: See this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53430999/how-to-sync-a-variable-through-photon-pun

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to sync a variable through Photon PUN](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53430999/how-to-sync-a-variable-through-photon-pun)

Comment: i need just want to have access to that component that I marked in the image